# Advance in or advance to

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the preposition for this:

> In life, you have to secure the basics first, before you advance **in/to** another stage.

Can you use them interchangeably?

While googling, some entries have advance in, and others are advance to...(**advance** the evidence **to** authorites, xxx person **advance** **to** the world cup)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They cannot generally (in normal context) be used interchangeably.

Used with *in*, you are advancing something from one position to another position within a specific unit:

> I am studying Algebra. I used to be the lowest-ranked student in my class, but I have advanced *in* status and now am the highest-ranked student.
>   <sub>(The speaker stays within the unit of Algebra)</sub>

Used with *to*, you are advancing from one specific unit to another:

> I was studying Algebra, but have passed the final test and now will advance *to* a higher level class, Calculus.
>   <sub>(The speaker changes to a new Maths unit)</sub>

In your example, "you" are in a basic stage of life (a unit) and are advancing ***to*** another stage (another unit), not advancing within the basic stage.

Answer (score 5):

We usually only use "into" with things which we could also use "in" with. We  usually talk about being "at a stage" rather than "in a stage" (I think this is because the metaphor conceives a "stage" as a point on a line, rather than a container), so we don't usually talk about moving "into a stage".